# Cannot declare a variable of static type 'System.IO.Path'

Tags: c#

When I try to compile my program it comes out with these errors:
Cannot declare a variable of static type 'System.IO.Path'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IO.Path'

I have components with these names

```
timer = timer1
openfolderbrowserdialog = inDirectoryDialog
openFileBrowserDialog = inFileDialog
checkbox1 = tempCompileCB
checkbox2 = finalCompileCB
textBox1 = inputDirectoryBox
textBox2 = inputFileBox
```

I don't know why its giving me this error and heres just the part of the program it gives a error for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace papyrusQuickCompile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string inDirectory;
        public string inFileName;
        public string inFileNameNoExtention;
        public Path compilerFolder;

        public Form1()
        {  
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 1 * 1000;
            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            compilerFolder = Path.Combine((AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ("compiler")));
            inDirectory = inDirectoryDialog.SelectedPath;
            inFileName = inFileDialog.SafeFileName;
            inFileNameNoExtention = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inFileDialog.SafeFileName);

            inputDirectoryBox.Text = inDirectory.ToString();
            inputFileBox.Text = inFileName.ToString();

            //temp compile checkbox
            if (tempCompileCB.Checked)
            {
                finalCompileCB.Checked = false;
                finalCompileCB.Enabled = false;
                finalCompileCB.Hide();
            }
             else if (!tempCompileCB.Checked)
            {
                finalCompileCB.Show();
                finalCompileCB.Enabled = true;
            }
            //final Compile Checkbox
            if (finalCompileCB.Checked)
            {
                tempCompileCB.Checked = false;
                tempCompileCB.Enabled = false;
                tempCompileCB.Hide();
            }
            else if (!finalCompileCB.Checked)
            {
                tempCompileCB.Show();
                tempCompileCB.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static class.

Comment: Change your `compilerFolder` type to string. That is what `Path.Combine` would return.

Comment: You probably meant to use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) or [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path.Combine` returns a `string`, not a `Path` object (and `Path` is a static class, so you can't have an instance of it anyways).

change

```
public Path compilerFolder;
```

to

```
public string compilerFolder;
```

Other ancillary suggestions:

- Use properties (or private fields) instead of public fields
- Don't use fields at all if they're only relevant to one method (which they appear to be unless you've got external code accessing them).

Answer (score 3):

[Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static class. You can't have an instance of it (your `compilerFolder` variable). Instead, store a string representing the path to the file.

Also, [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a string, so this will fix your second error, which you were getting due to trying to assign a string to a `Path` variable.